# .Net Core Razor Pages - Server Side Include

Tags: c#, html, .net-core, ssi

I'm unable to get server side includes (*.html files) working in a .net core razor pages web application. I've made sure to have the appropriate handler in my applicationhost.config, but I'm thinking there's a different issue here. Any help is appreciated.

Why am I doing this? I have multiple web applications sharing the server side include files (for navigation bar, footer, head content, etc..). Each of these different applications may be of different Microsoft web architecture. Our goal is to move everything to .net core, but we have lingering web forms projects to deal with along the way.

I have performed a work around by taking the SSI file contents and using @Html.Raw to serve up the content. This is probably wrong also.

Comment: Where do you want to store the included html? Another partial razor template? A file embedded in the assembly? A file from wwwroot or another filesystem folder, with in-memory caching?

Comment: I was going to put these partial HTML files in the wwwroot folder so that the additional applications on my site could access them. We have several other applications on this site which include web forms and mvc on .Net 4.8. The goal is to host all of the applications in IIS on the same site.

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and changed the file extension of the html files into cshtml which allowed me to treat these files as partial views. I'm using a prebuild event to copy these files from a shared solution folder into my project Pages/Shared/ssi folder. I also copy those partials into wwwroot/ssi for the other applications to use via SSI. Eventually all of the apps will use the partial views instead.

The problem with this solution is that it is not necessarily clear that all edits need to happen in the shared solution folder instead of directly in the project, but the documentation for the project will address this. I tried using linked files, but only one link to a specific file can be made in a project.

Not a perfect solution (to the problem), but this not a perfect website either.